# Connect to cluster through VPC

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, kubernetes, amazon-vpc

I have a kubernetes cluster with ec2 nodes, how can I connect to pods in this cluster externally from my local machine or another ec2 instance not in the cluster? I have the VPC ID and the cluster namespace.

Comment: https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/access-application-cluster/create-external-load-balancer/

Answer (score 1):

AWS announced [EKS ( Elastic Kubernetes Service )](https://aws.amazon.com/eks/) as new service few days ago. However it is still in preview the time that I am writing this answer.

Anyway, you can use [kops](https://github.com/kubernetes/kops) which is built for this purpose ; to make marriage between k8s and AWS .

You will do something like the following:

```
kops create cluster --name=k8s.example.com \
   --state=s3://cluster-state \
   --zones=eu-west-1a \
   --node-count=2 \ 
   --node-size=t2.micro \ 
   --master-size=t2.micro \ 
   --dns-zone=k8s.example.com
```

Comment: Is there a way to do this without kops?